# NHibernate LINQ solution to count SUM

Tags: .net, sql, linq, nhibernate

I'am using NHibernate `3.3.1.4000` and FluentNHibernate `1.3.0.733` for SQL Server 2012

I have next classes:

```
class Foo {
    public virtual bool Enabled;
    public virtual IList<Bar> Children;
}

class Bar {
    public virtual Foo Parent;
}
```

and want to count number of all `Bar` items for enabled `Foo` items.

```
Session.Query<Foo>(x => x.Enabled).Cacheable().Sum(x => x.Children.Count)
```

but I receive `Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException` exception:

> Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Sum[Foo](.Where[Foo](.CacheableFoo, Quote((x, ) => (x.Enabled)), ), Quote((x, ) => (x.Children.Count)), )]

All works fine if I do sum on client side (with loading all `Bar` items) like this:

```
Session.Query<Foo>(x => x.Enabled).Cacheable().ToList().Sum(x => x.Children.Count)
```

Can you suggest best decision to do this on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var childCount = (from x in Session.Query<Foo>()
                  from child in x.Children
                  where x.Enabled
                  select child).Count();
```

You should be able to add the .Cacheable() somewhere in there (either after Query() or before Count()).

Answer (score 0):

I think the part `Sum(x => x.Children.Count)` causes problems. Rewrite your query like so:

```cs
Session.Query<Foo>(x => x.Enabled).Cacheable()
   .Select(x => x.Children.Count).Sum()
```

Comment: Same exception type: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Sum(.Select[Foo,System.Int32](.Where[Foo](.Cacheable[Foo](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Foo], ), Quote((x, ) => (x.Enabled)), ), Quote((x, ) => (x.Children.Count)), ), )] ...

Comment: What if you use `Count()` (the extension method) in stead of `Count` (the IList property)?

Comment: Very close exception: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Sum(.Select[Foo,System.Int32](.Where[Foo](.Cacheable[Foo](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Foo], ), Quote((x, ) => (x.Enabled)), ), Quote((x, ) => (.Count[Bar](x.Children, ))), ), )]

Comment: Oooh this [linq to nhibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4675/why-i-hate-implementing-linq)!! Does it work without `Cacheable`?

Comment: Same problem with both cases (`Count` and `Count()`): Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown.[.Sum(.Select[Foo,System.Int32](.Where[Foo](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Foo], Quote((x, ) => (x.Enabled)), ), Quote((x, ) => (.Count[Bar](x.Children, ))), ), )]  :-(